# Как правильно сделать платную версию приложение Android

Tags: android, google-play

Такой вопрос, есть приложение в `Google Play` оно бесплатно, но в нем есть реклама, нужно сделать платную версию этого приложения, но без рекламы. Как правильно сделать платную версию приложения? Поменять названия package и залить как новое приложение в `Google Play`? Или есть какие-то другие варианты?

Comment: Другой вариант - добавить отключение рекламы после покупки данной опции через In-App Purchase.

Comment: @eugeneek А какой вариант лучше и практичнее? То-есть, если платная версия отличается от бесплатной только тем, что нет рекламы, то лучше делать через In-App Purchase?

Comment: Думаю да, так будет логичней.